# How to remove /page/2/ from home page?

Tags: pagination, urls, performance

First of all: I don't understand the meaning or the action that http://myurl/page/2 does?

I checked the Net tab in `Firebug` and saw that my page takes more than 3 seconds to load **/page/2**... but I don't need pagination at my front page at all. I don't get where it comes from either.

My question: how do I disable / remove this and show it only when pagination is needed?

This is the query I am using to get posts:

```
<?php
query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 10));
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```

Comment: Is this a pre-built Theme you are using or did you make this yourself? It's important to know that to help you on this one.

Comment: This is a pre-built theme that I am using.

Comment: Does the Theme have auto-loading on for posts? "Infinite Scroll" sometimes they call it.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't... It's the theme "Responsive" btw.

Comment: /page/2 is typically for pagination, like having more than one set of results to go through -- like Posts or a list of Pages. That query, normally would be saying "get the next set of pages". Anywhere on your page that might be doing that?

Comment: Could it be that "2" is an very big attachment (picture) that's eating away your connection, which is attached to that particular page?

Comment: showposts is deprecated and should be replaced by posts_per_page

Comment: Well, I do have a link that links to a page where you can see the other posts, but that one links to a different page (different URL).... and thus, it's not that one.

Besides, when I go to the page/2/ url, it just gets my home page, it's not a pagination at all, it seems.

Comment: the number of pages you have is based on the contents of the main query. page/2 doesn't do anything for you because you are overwriting the main query with `query_posts`. [Read this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) to learn why you should never use `query_posts`.

Comment: CAI, thanks, will change that one. @Milo what do you suggest in that case?

Comment: If this is just a static page and there's no pagination, then consider using a static front page under Settings > Reading and creating a new WP_Query for your random posts list.

Comment: And what if I wouldn't do that? I mean, I will consider it for sure... but will that solve my problem? And isn't there any other way to solve this? @Milo

Comment: @denis.stoyanov, no, cause it's the exact same as on my front-page. I don't use images.

Comment: if you just don't want pagination to appear, then modify the template to remove whatever is generating pagination.

Comment: That's the whole problem @Milo: there is nothing that generates pagination. Nothing in my template at all... That's why I asked this question.

Comment: If your reading settings are set to display posts on the homepage but the template file doesn't show those posts that is exactly the problem and changing the settings like Milo said is the correct way to fix it.

Comment: So, because I set "display posts on homepage", it automatically thinks I need pagination and adds it? 

So, I need to make a static front page with a WP query, correct? And then, the problem will be fixed?

Comment: Just because your template is creating a new query it doesn't mean the original query isn't running (and not being used). That's why you're getting page 2 but it's not showing anything. Either change the reading settings to show a static front page or modify the existing query instead of using query_posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the front page is set to display posts then the query for those posts will run regardless of wether your theme shows these posts or not. That's why you're getting pagination with no posts. You can test this by temporarily removing your themes front-page.php (or whatever it is). You should see all your posts with correct pagination.

You have 2 options to get around this:

### Use a static front page

If you set the front page to static (this can be an empty page) the original query for the homepage will now be just this page - therefore, no pagination.

### Alter the main query

Instead of creating a new query using `query_posts` (which you shouldn't be doing anyway - but that's [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)), alter the original query. You should be able to do this using the `pre_get_posts` hook and a combination of `is_home()` and `is_front_page()`. Something like this:

```
/**
 * Alters the font-page main query
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_217284_alter_front_page_query' );
function wpse_217284_alter_front_page_query( $query ) {

    // don't run on the backend
    if ( is_admin() )
      return;

    // Only run on the front page main query
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_front_page() ) {

        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
    }

    return;
}
```

*Note, this isn't tested and is just an example, so may not work as is, but it should give you an idea of what to do.*

Comment: Thanks man. I will check this out and let you guys know. Appreciated.

Comment: The code snippet does not work indeed. But I don't get your explanation...  so if I use a static front page, than it's impossible to have pagination? And what does this main query alter function do to be precise?

Comment: If you use a static front page it's not impossible to get pagination - you just won't get pagination unless its needed. The [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) docs tells you what it does. It alters the main query before it is run which means you don't need to use `query_posts` which you were before. The `is_front_page` makes sure it only runs on the home page. The rest should be self explanatory or easy enough to figure out.

Comment: The code I posted should work as long as you don't use `query_posts` or set up any other query and set the front page to display posts.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)